# Counter Example Problem ( Two variable function ).

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In the given situation we show that , either the statement is true or we find a counter example to prove it wrong ,

> If $\lim_{y \to 0} f(0,y)=0$ , then , $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}
>  f(x,y)=0$

I tried to solve this using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition but couldn't get through , so I came up with the following counter example :

$f(x,y) = \dfrac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$

Clearly ,  $\lim_{y \to 0} f(0,y)=0$

But when we consider , $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ , the limit doesn't exists. (Considering the path along $y=mx$ shows that limit depends on $m$ and is not unique).

Is the above example okay ?
Or I need to work through the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition ?

Comment: Your example works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the fact that if you have two different sequences of points converging to $(0,0)$ on which the function does not converge to the same limit, then the function does not have a limit at $(0,0)$. This is true, and is the correct approach. However, you should try to prove this approach itself using the epsilon-delta definition at least once, just to see how it works.